# Will my Joomla! 3.x extensions work with Joomla! 2.5?

Tags: php, joomla, extension-methods, joomla2.5

I am going to develop a extension for joomla 2.5 using joomla 3.x will it work in joomla 2.5 if i place the joomla version in the xml file?

Comment: If you are doing Joomla development, you might like to create an account at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and post your questions in that dedicated community.  (Neil is over there too.)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is maybe.

Many API elements in Joomla 2.5 were deprecated and newer ones were introduced in Joomla 3.x.

Most extension creators have dropped support for Joomla 2.5 but it looks like [Joomla Component Generator](https://www.componentgenerator.com) still supports older versions of Joomla. There may be others.